# Bind Slider Value to ProgressBar effectively?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, expression-blend

So what I would like to do is control a Progressbar width by way of a slider with just xaml. What's below sort of works, but it only increases the ProgressBar's value slightly. After playing with the min/max, not sure where my fault is. I saw workarounds using a rectangle and some codebehind, but I'd like to interact with the ProgressBar specifically for this example. Thanks for any shared insight!

```
<Slider Orientation="Vertical" 
        Value="{Binding ElementName=progress, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<ProgressBar x:Name="progress" 
         Height="20" 
         IsIndeterminate="False" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the Minimum and Maximum on the Slider to match the ProgressBar

```
<Slider Orientation="Vertical" 
        Value="{Binding ElementName=progress, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
/>

<ProgressBar x:Name="progress" 
         Height="20" 
         IsIndeterminate="False" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
```

or bind the min/max if required

```
<Slider Orientation="Vertical" 
    Value="{Binding ElementName=progress, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Minimum="{Binding ElementName=progress, Path=Minimum}" 
    Maximum="{Binding ElementName=progress, Path=Maximum}"
/>
```

Comment: Oh wow completely forgot about the min/max on the slider as well! Evidence of a late night detail oversight haha thanks so much! :)